# USB drive is visible in Windows 7's device manager, but NOT in file explorer (my computer) or disk management

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, usb, external-hard-drive

It's an old external usb driver in NTFS that was working fine with my windows 7, and later I formatted it into ExFat by my MBP that I hoped it could be consumed by both PC and Mac. Unfortunately the Windows 7 could NOT find it any more (while works perfect with my Mac). The USB drive is visible in Windows 7's device manager (good status, running), but NOT in file explorer (my computer) or disk management (therefore I have no way to format it by Windows).

Anyone could help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does it display anything in diskpart using the show partitions list? It might simply be Microsoft not understanding standard partition ID's and requiring some special codes or names.

Comment: I'd definitely second @John's idea to check if your external HDD is listed in DiskPart. Another thing you should try is backing up your data on the MBP  and then reformat the USB drive in FAT32 instead. Afterwards, transfer back your files to the drive and check again if you will be able to see it anywhere else in Windows 7. Hope this works. Keep us posted with the troubleshooting! :)

Comment: thanks guys, but the cmd tool DiskPart didn't list the missing external drive.